# Bazel sha256 checksum

Tags: java, bazel, coursier

I'm working on migrating our project to Bazel.

WORKSPACE

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")


RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG = "2.10"
RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA = "1bbf2e48d07686707dd85357e9a94da775e1dbd7c464272b3664283c9c716d26"
 
http_archive(
    name = "rules_jvm_external",
    strip_prefix = "rules_jvm_external-%s" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
    sha256 = RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA,
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/archive/%s.zip" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
)

load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")
 
maven_install(
    name = "maven",
    artifacts = [
        "com.foo:bar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
        "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9",
    ], 
    repositories = [ 

        "https://our-maven-repo",
    ],
    resolve_timeout = 200,
    fail_on_missing_checksum = False,
    fetch_sources = True
    
)
```

BUILD

```
java_library(
    name = "our-name",
    srcs = glob([
        "src/main/java/**/*.java"
    ]),
    resources = glob([
        "src/main/resources/**",
    ]),
    deps = [
        "@maven//:com.foo_bar",
        "@maven//:org.apache.commons_commons-lang3"
    ],
)
```

When I run:

```
PS> bazel fetch //:our-name
```

Output

```
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'maven' which is a coursier_fetch (rule definition at C:/users/name/_bazel_name/73nyktky/external/rules_jvm_external/coursier.bzl:620:18):
 - C:/users/name/_bazel_name/73nyktky/external/rules_jvm_external/defs.bzl:89:5
 - C:/project/WORKSPACE:19:1
INFO: Repository 'maven' used the following cache hits instead of downloading the corresponding file.
 * Hash '8f35f92fb8e021f96b3aa8145c66c3b2e29295baabb28ff50569e613438afcbd' for https://github.com/coursier/coursier/releases/download/v2.0.0-RC3-4/coursier.jar
If the definition of 'maven' was updated, verify that the hashes were also updated.
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'maven':
   Error while obtaining the sha256 checksum of v1/https/our-repo/prod/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar: java.io.IOException: ERROR: src/main/native/windows/process.cc(199): CreateProcessW("python" C:/users/name/_bazel_name/73nyktky/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/hash/sha256.py C:/users/name/_bazel_name/73nyktky/external/maven/v1/https/ourrepo/prod/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar artifact.sha256): The system cannot find the file specified.
 (error: 2)
ERROR: C:/project/BUILD:1:1: no such package '@maven//': Error while obtaining the sha256 checksum of v1/https/our-repo/prod/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar: java.io.IOException: ERROR: src/main/native/windows/process.cc(199): CreateProcessW("python" C:/users/name/_bazel_name/73nyktky/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/hash/sha256.py C:/users/name/_bazel_name/73nyktky/external/maven/v1/https/ourrepo/prod/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar artifact.sha256): The system cannot find the file specified.
 (error: 2) and referenced by '//:our-name'
ERROR: Evaluation of query "deps(//:our-name)" failed: errors were encountered while computing transitive closure
Loading: 0 packages loaded
```

org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9 jar does get download, along with a sha1 and md5 hash. The com.foo:bar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT jar does NOT get downloaded. The sha1 and md5 do get downloaded.

I think my issue is that our repo does not have any sha256 hashes to download so the fetch (or build) fail with that error. However when i look at the actual rules_jvm_external https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external#checksum-verification it seems that sha256 is not mandatory?

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Bazel 1.1.0
Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1803, OS build 17134.1069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rules_jvm_external` maintainer here.

```
ERROR: C:/project/BUILD:1:1: no such package '@maven//': Error while obtaining the sha256 checksum of v1/https/our-repo/prod/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar: java.io.IOException: ERROR: src/main/native/windows/process.cc(199): CreateProcessW("python" C:/users/name/_bazel_name/73nyktky/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/hash/sha256.py C:/users/name/_bazel_name/73nyktky/external/maven/v1/https/ourrepo/prod/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar artifact.sha256): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is the real error where Windows' `CreateProcessW` is complaining that `python` is not available. This is previously reported [in this issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/issues/281) as well. We added SHA256 checking in 2.3, and unfortunately this depends on Python.

Do you have `python` installed? There is an outstanding PR that [drops the dependency here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/pull/296).

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try and get Python installed today and try again.